# All Apple Internet Apps are SLOW in Yosemite

Tags: macos, safari, mail.app, mac-appstore, messages

A few days after upgrading to Yosemite, I started noticing that Safari was moving VERY SLOWLY. After a day or two of this it stopped loading webpages at all! So I switched to using Chrome, then my Mail app stopped receiving mail, it would send mail but again it is VERY slow. Then messages wouldn't sign into my AIM account, and I noticed that the App Store won't load any pages at all. I've searched around the web and found that some other people had the same issue, [here's a link to one comment](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27249334#27249334) on an apple discussion thread that helped me several times, but now that doesn't even help anymore!

So the question: has anybody over here had this issue and found a solution to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to test, did you use the "ping google.com" in terminal and let it run use "ctrl+c" to stop, while monitoring the numbers, it should be around 20ms or less.

Comment: Is Chrome still working fine? And how was Safari moving slowly? Was the user interface (chrome) unresponsive? Spinning beach ball of death? Or did the pages just not load / load slowly?

Comment: Chrome works great, as far as Safari goes, the interface works fine (no beach ball of death or anything) it just would take a coon's age to load any webpage.

Comment: @Buscar웃 when I ping google my response time is from 22.445 to 40.944 ms.

Comment: ok, the ping is bit on slow end but still fine and not the reason, your network connection is fine in general. Lets test the specifics: Under Apple (top left) select Location, then Network Preferences than in new window select Assist me- than Diagnostics and let it run for the Location you are using.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It say: "Your Internet connection appears to be working correctly."

Comment: ok run this in Terminal to see who is using your Internet "sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP" see anyone who should not be using it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I got a lot of info returned! What am I looking for?

Comment: I know :) do you see anything that should not be using Internet (that you did not ask for), you should see Safari, Chrome, Mail ect.. I am trying to find out if something is eating up your Internet bandwidth resulting in slow connection. You are reporting multiple apps been slow or not working at all (beside Safari), Mail, AIM, Apple Store ect... Cloud you look up and report your DNS numbers (something like 192.168...) in the Network Preferences. You could just add Googles DNS "8.8.8.8" to use it.

Comment: The DNS was 192.168.2.1, I added 8.8.8.8 but it didn't seem to make any difference for Safari (it still won't load any webpage at all). In terminal these are things that I don't know what they are: launchd, node, beam.smp, redis-ser, celapid, apsd, xcscontro, kdc, cupsd, Core\x20S, ocspd. Do any of those seem suspicious to you right off the bat, or can you tell me how to research to find out what they are?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I appreciate you time, did you see my previous comment?

Comment: @szupie Chrome is working great as is Firefox...

Comment: Going along with @Buscar웃's DNS theory, can you `ping www.google.com` (and stop) again and copy the IP address (`PING www.google.com (**XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX**): 56 data bytes`), then paste it into Safari and see if it loads?

Comment: @szupie I pasted the IP into Safari, and the page finally loaded after about 75 seconds...

Comment: You have to much strange stuff using your Internet, I only have Skype, Mail, Firefox, cupsd, lauchd and apsd.  I have no idea what the others are you are reporting. "node, beam.smp, redis-ser, celapid, xcscontro, kdc, Core\x20S, ocspd"

Comment: In light of all the stuff you have running, I am wondering it you could disable your Virus scan like Avast, or whatever you are using.